# How can I get the selected appointment (Id?) in Outlook calendar when i click on it?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I can get a list of all calendar items but how can i pick the right one?
How can i compare the IDs within the collection and the on screen clicked?

```
public void OnActionCallback(IRibbonControl control, bool isPressed)
        {
            _Outlook.Application oApp = null;
            oApp = new _Outlook.Application();
            var appointments = oApp.Session.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar).Items;

            foreach (AppointmentItem item in appointments)
            {
                JobTimeLine j = new JobTimeLine() 
                {
                    PostingDate = item.Start,
                    No = item.RequiredAttendees,
                    WorkTypeCode=item.Subject,
                    FromTime=item.Start.ToLocalTime(),
                    ToTime=item.End.ToLocalTime(),
                    ShipToName = null,
                    JobNo = item.ConversationTopic,
                    JobTaskNo = item.Body,
                    PlaceOfWork = "Büro",
                    Description= null,
                    Description2= null,
                    ShipToCostumerNo= "D20101",
                };

            MessageBox.Show("GlobalAppointmentID = " + item.GlobalAppointmentID + j.GetOutput());
            }
}
```

I am getting a collection but i need to pick exactly one item from it, which is clicked/selected/loaded in the outlook app.

Answer (score 1):

The currently selected items in the Outlook explorer view can be retrieved by using the [Selection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.selection) property of the `Explorer` class which returns a `Selection` object that contains the item or items that are selected in the explorer window. The location of a selection in the explorer can be in the view list, the appointment list or task list in the To-Do Bar, or the daily tasks list in a calendar view. For more information, see the [Location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.selection.location) property.

```
private void DisplaySelectedItems()
{
    Outlook.Selection selection =
        Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection;
    for (int i = 1; i <= selection.Count; i++)
    {
        object myItem = selection[i];
    }
}
```

To get items displayed in the inspector windows in Outlook you may use the [CurrentItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspector.currentitem) property of the `Inspector` class (see the [ActiveInspector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.activeinspector) method of the Outlook `Application` class).

Also in the code I've noticed that a new Outlook Application instance is created:

```
_Outlook.Application oApp = null;
            oApp = new _Outlook.Application();
```

In the ribbon callbacks you can use the `Application` property of your add-in class or just access it by using the `Globals` static class in the following way:

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that next week.